# Best way to set up new outlets in workshop

Tags: electrical, woodworking

Context: I have a workshop used for woodworking. On one wall, I have a two-pole (240v) 30a outlet and a regular 120v 20a outlet. I'm building some cabinetry and I plan to convert the outlets in the wall into a junction box and mount the outlets onto the cabinets in a more accessible location.

I'm curious how I should set up the new boxes because I was wanting to do the following:

- One single 20a 240v receptacle (from the 30a circuit - uses only black wires - reserved for future table saw)
- One duplex 20a 120v receptacle (from the 30a circuit - fin removed, using black & white wires from 30a circuit)
- One duplex 20a 120v receptacle (from the 20a circuit)

I don't think I can put them all in a 3-gang box since I won't find an outlet cover with two duplex / one single. So I guess I need 2 separate boxes.

I could do a 2-gang box with four receptacles (the four 120v ones), and a single gang box with the 240v. This would look cleaner in a way, but the wiring is probably messier since there would need to be wires going between the two boxes.

Or, I could do a single gang box with 120v duplex, and a two-gang box with a combo 120/240 receptacles, using a cover like [this](https://www.supplyhouse.com/Steel-City-RS-3-4-Square-Surface-Cover-for-One-Single-One-Duplex-Flush-Receptacle).

I guess I'm leaning towards the latter but it would be nice if I could have put this all together in one box.

(If it matters, one of the 120v circuits will power a shopvac and the rest of the plugs will power a tool (router/miter saw/table saw etc). Only one tool will run at once but vac/tool will be on separate circuits so they can run together).

edit: The 30a circuit is wired for a dryer but is unused. The electrician put that in when I asked him for a 240v circuit in case I wanted to re-wire the table saw.

edit: Upon further inspection, my 30a circuit is only wired with 10/2 romex, so my proposal isn't going to work without running new cable anyway.

Comment: *won't find an outlet cover with two duplex / one single* - You are in a woodworking workshop. Make one.

Comment: Your plan ignores the fact that you cannot safely directly connect either 20 amp outlet to a 30 amp circuit! You could overload a 20 amp outlet to 30 amps and burn up your wiring and/or outlet.

Comment: Other reasons too. Devices which UL has certified to plug into 20A outlets are required to reliably trip a 20A breaker if they fail. May not trip a 30A.

Comment: Are the existing circuits run using cables, or individual wires in conduit?

Comment: @DoxyLover how is that different from running 15a plugs on a 20a circuit? This is the reason the 20a plug is different from a 15 plug.

Comment: To be clear, the circuit is unused today. So if the problem is the breaker rating I can swap that for a 20a breaker.

Comment: @RyanSilva, residential 15A receptacles are usually rated for 20A passthrough, and the assumption is that nothing drawing more than a nominal 15A will be used on them. Things are different when you start dealing with power tools and industrial equipment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can't put 20A receptacles on a 30A circuit.

If your 30A circuit is 4-wire, you can convert it to a feeder to a sub panel.  Then, you can fit the requisite **20 amp** 120V and 240V circuits as you wish, without any real restriction.

However a 30A feeder cannot have any receptacles at all, so if you jury rigged this off the dryer circuit as many do, that whole thing will need to be re-done (with separate neutral and ground if not already so). Once the subpanel is in, you can run a 30A circuit *back* to the dryer. That will use 100% of the feeder's capacity when you're drying, so don't use other tools then.

---

Since your 240V loads are 15A or 20A, you can use *normal* 240V sockets - you don't need to pay a fortune for the wackadoodle twist-locks LOL.  If your community prefers those, pay them no mind.  It's your shop.

[image]

You might also think about [*multi-wire branch circuits*](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/238808/wiring-for-switched-nema-6-20r-and-5-20r-in-same-box-in-garage) (MWBC) to the cabinets. These use 4 wires and connect both 120V and 240V outlets to the 20A circuits. They even make "combo" receptacles that accommodate both 120V and 240V outlets on one yoke. You get dual 120V "half circuits" so you can run two 16A loads, one one each half-circuit. Any 240V loads add amps to both 120V half-circuits.

If the cabinets will be screwed to the wall, they can be cabled in with normal Romex as long as the Romex is physically protected.

If the cabinets will be free moving, I would use cord-and-plug connections and EMT or FMC metal conduit with metal boxes for the wiring internal to the cabinets.  Have *proper cordage* (SO, SW, SJOOW and any of those "S" cables) for the cord/plug connections, and proper strain reliefs where they enter the metal box knockout. Design the cabinets to protect the cord from injury.  No inspector will argue with that!

However if you cord-and-plug run an MWBC, you'll need a 4-wire 20A socket.  Straight blade 14-20 sockets are rare, probably forcing you into the far more common but expensive L14-20 twist-locks. However you could just hard-wire it with FMC or a AC/MC wire whip.

Comment: It's a dryer outlet but it's not being currently for anything. When I had the basement renovated I asked the electrician to give me a 240v outlet for future use. He put in a dryer outlet. Thanks for all the detailed info. But why can't you put 20a receptacles on a 30a circuit? How is it different from 15a receptacles on a 20a circuit? And why do products like [this](https://www.leviton.com/en/products/5842-I) exist if you can't do what I'm suggesting?

Comment: Re-reading your paragraph about MWBC, is that different from what I'm proposing? Except instead of the combo receptacle I was just going to put the dual "half circuits" on a separate receptacle. If the problem is just the breaker rating, I can swap that for 20a since there's no dryer. The only other unusual thing would be the oversized 10 gauge wire, which should be fine.

Comment: 1 - There is a very specific exemption for 15A + 20A, with a lot of very good reasoning behind it. 2 - The product you linked is to allow 20A 120V + 20A 240V on one circuit. That is absolutely fine, but you still have to breaker at 20A. 3 - Yes, the real issue is the breaker - swap it for a 20A and you're fine.

Comment: Interesting. I thought the breaker was just sized for the wire. But if I use a 20a breaker, i might have a 15a saw (240v on the two hots) and a 10a shopvac (120v on hot/neutral) which should be fine on 10 gauge wires but won't it likely trip a 20amp 2-pole breaker?

Comment: If it does trip the breaker, @RyanSilva, then the breaker is doing its job by protecting the wiring. Sure, **your** _in-wall_ wiring can handle more current than that, but the shop vac's power cord can't and the saw's probably won't, either. Also, neither device will use that much power other than at startup (or if stalled).

Comment: @FreeMan I measured the vac at 9 amps. The saw I don't have so I'm not sure what it would actually pull. But my point is if the saw + vac using the combo receptacle are going to flip a 20a breaker, then I probably need a sub panel.

Comment: @RyanSilva NEC 210.21 is the reason.  Was the dryer outlet 4-wire or only 3?  If 3, you may have a dumb electrician. On that outlet you linked, **both the sockets are 20 amps**, it does not support your concept. Yes, you don't need to use that for MWBC, you can use 3 separate receptacles if you prefer.  And yes, changing the breaker to 20A is a fine answer.  Although I like "subpanel" because you'll get more total power out of it.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I'm an idiot. When I saw the dryer-looking outlet I assumed he must have pulled 10/3 wire just like he should have for the dryer. I just pulled it open and it's 10/2 romex with no neutral. He put in a NEMA 10-50 outlet. In fact, my *actual dryer* was newly wired with a 3-wire setup. FML. Looks like if I want a sub panel I need it rewired.

Comment: That's a code violation in both cases. I would report it to the inspector as that guy needs a talking-to.  3-prong NEMA 10s have been illegal since 1996 *for dryers/ranges* and 1966 for everything else.  And using 10/2 ground as neutral has never been legal.    You can change it to NEMA 6-30 and run 30A/240V devices, or breaker to 20A and receptacle to 6-20 and run smaller 240V devices.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I'll probably change the breaker and put in the right plug for sawstop which they spec as NEMA 6-15P. I'll just run my vac off an outlet in another part of the room. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: @Ryan yeah you could do a subpanel and power as much as 30A of 240V loads, however you'd have to keep 120V loads out of that subpanel. It can't support them.

Comment: @RyanSilva seriously follow up with the inspector about a _NEW_ installation of a 10-50! That is a violation and the local inspectors need to know about it!

Comment: @FreeMan For the dryer or the shop? For the shop I think I'm fine to just replace the outlet and the breaker once I get a tool that needs 240v. For the dryer I'm trying to decide how mad to be, because the new dryer is on the other side of the house from the panel.

Comment: The comments [here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/243656/best-way-to-set-up-new-outlets-in-workshop/243657?noredirect=1#comment474614_243657), which Harper recommended you report to the inspector. Your electrician did illegal work and shouldn't get away with it.

Comment: @FreeMan you mean 6-50 or 14-50 I think :)  10-50 is still illegal.  Unfortunately welders and other hobbies have chosen 10-50 as their "private standard" and so people with opinions tend to want NEMA 10.  I could see an electrician doing it so often for so long they forget it's illegal.

Comment: 10-50 is what the OP put in [his comment](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/243656/best-way-to-set-up-new-outlets-in-workshop/243657?noredirect=1#comment474614_243657), so that's what I repeated.

Comment: 10-50 is what they put in the shop. It's illegal as wired and shouldn't have passed but for a table saw it will be OK if I just change the breaker and the outlet to 6-15P. The laundry is 10-30 and run with 10/2 romex with ground connected to neutral. The contractor is telling me it's fine because it passed both inspections. Looking for help from architect and the city if they get back to me.

Comment: 10/2 on a dryer has never been legal, so it sounds like something the inspector missed or is not aware is a codevio.  Sometimes electrician-inspector relationships can be a bit ... inbred.  There can't be a local amendment there because the reason is technical - NM grounds aren't insulated well enough to be neutrals.  NEMA 10 should not have passed inspection after NEC 1996 was adopted, unless there are local amendments.