# How can I branch off an exterior wall outlet for a post outlet without cutting into the wall?

Tags: electrical, receptacle

I have an exterior outlet/receptacle on the front of my house that I'd like use to extend power to a location about 45' away, where I have a small gravel parking area (I occasionally need to run things like car battery chargers here).  Existing outlet is similar to this:

[image]

I'd like to eliminate the long extension cord I've been using, and build some kind of permanent or even semi-permanent outlet (doesn't need to be always-on) on a post adjacent to the parking area, if that's at all possible.  Is there a practical way to achieve this without having to punch through the house wall for a new cable run, and with minimal trenching?

Existing outlet is on the porch, a couple feet above grade.

Keeping the extension cord isn't the end of the world, but...

[image]

Editing to add pics of the present sitch:
[image]
[image]

Comment: You won't avoid trenching, but you may be able to extend the box enough to drop conduit out the bottom on the exterior of the wall. I'll let those more knowledgeable post actual answers. I'd like to know whether that's a viable strategy.

Comment: Can't see any reason why you wouldn't be able to run conduit from the box into the ground. Be sure to use an expansion coupler at both ends. Minimize trenching by minimizing the cable run, otherwise, your trench is your trench. You can minimize _depth_ by using conduit the whole way - as little as 6" of cover in steel conduit! I went with Sched 40 PVC and 18" of cover - used a post hole digger to loosen the dirt, then scooped it out to make the trench.

Comment: If the circuit is GFCI protected *at the source*, then direct burial can be done at 12" depth.  I would use a 20A "240V" circuit and run 4-wire as a MWBC using a Leviton 5842 socket. That way you can do 120V stuff out there, and also do perfectly respectable level 2 EV charging (100-150 miles per 10 hours).

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica what do you mean by "at the source?"  On a GFCI breaker?

Comment: @Huesmann I mean "prior to the beginning of the underground run in question".  So in your case the GFCI could be in the box you are taking photos of.  (though I'm not a fan of GFCI receptacles outside.) It appears you already have a box extension, just get one with ports.  If I'm wrong and that's a regular box, replace with one with ports.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I think what I have on there is a weatherproof extender like this guy: https://www.homedepot.com/p/BELL-N3R-Aluminum-Gray-1-Gang-Weatherproof-Extension-Ring-Electrical-Outlet-Extender-1-in-Deep-No-Ground-Screws-5406-0/204829633  Based on the depth of the siding box, I think I'd need to stack on a weatherproof extension ring with ports, like the one in Encerwal's answer, because none of the ported boxes I see have the ports toward the front of the box.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica could you also elaborate on "240V"—how would that be accomplished here?

Comment: @Huesmann Oh, I see what you mean, that thing's a cover not a junction box.  Yeah, Ecnerwal's advice is best.  On the 120/240V trick, you can run /3 cable to it from a 240V breaker, and do this.  https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/238814/47125 Note the weird lower socket - that's a 240V/20A socket.  The only trick is, for GFCI protection it would need a 240V GFCI breaker - costly.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica the existing outlet is on only a 14/2 circuit.

Answer (score 6):

[image: Weatherproof box extension image from zoro.com no endorsement implied]

As @isherwood suggests, you can use a weatherproof box extender to extend your weatherproof box and gain conduit access without going into the wall, if surface-mounted conduit passes muster with any potential other party who might not approve of that in that highly visible location. *i.e.* **Spouse Approval Factor**, if applicable.

But you'll need to dig to bury the conduit acceptably per table [300.5](http://adamselectric.coop/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Minimum-Cover-Requirements.pdf) [as little as 4" with sufficient (4", extending 6" beyond to the sides - basically another sidewalk/path) concrete cover for RMC or IMC types, on down to 24" for direct burial without conduit, which I Do Not Recommend] - at which point you might *consider* the straight shot into the basement wall, as it's less trenching, less conduit, and removes the complex dance (and potential appearance issue) to get conduit up on the porch.

Note that paying for 2" of concrete cover can save a lot of digging even with nonmetallic conduit types.

You could also put an inlet in an in-use cover/box on a short post near the porch, connected to conduit connected to the outlet at the driveway, and connect the porch outlet to that with a short cord when needed. However, at that point simply providing a neat box with a door on the post at the driveway to contain the coiled up longer cord when not in use is less hassle overall, since you don't have to dig a trench and "it's not the end of the world" to keep it.

[Alternate 300.5 link.](https://up.codes/viewer/illinois/nfpa-70-2020/chapter/3/wiring-methods-and-materials#300.5_%28A%29)

Since you're putting the post/outlet there, consider extending the post upwards and having a light there as well.

Comment: The light is a good idea, and something I recall thinking about long ago.  Although I'd have to figure out how to do a taller post.

Comment: Yard post lights are a product you can simply buy and install, complete with post.

Comment: We have cars with dead batteries being charged in a "small gravel parking lot".  I sense the spousal aesthetic demands are minimal here.  +1.

Comment: @jay613 that's correct, considering my wife spray paints her crafts on the lawn and DGAF about overspray on the grass. :-D

Comment: @Ecnerwal what type of electric box could be mounted on a 3" dia light pole in a weatherproof fashion?  Or would you recommend just leaving the outlet on a separate post?

Answer (score 0):

If you *really* want to avoid trenching you could consider a 12V solution.  This could power your battery chargers, some lighting and some other things.  With that, if you rarely need 120V you run an extension cord from the house.

I don't think this is the best solution but depending on how much you hate digging it might help you.

Start with a box extender per @Ecnerwal's answer.  Lots of good advice there.
Then, a short conduit to an adjacent box where you put a 12V PSU.   Then you run 12V direct bury cable from there into the ground.  Slit the ground with a shovel and shove the cable into the slit, about 6 inches deep, while prying it open with the shovel.  You never move any earth.

Use 14/2 UF or 14/2 landscape cable.  The UF is sturdier and appears to be about the same price.   I would use that.  But it won't be obvious to anyone inspecting it that it's low voltage so you could attach some tags to it to make it clear.